# Regex replace curly brackets and double quotes but preserve the text

Tags: regex

I have the following demo data:

```
"${var.some_text.anothertext.test}"
"${var.some_text3}"
"${var.some_text2.anothertext}"
```

I wanna be able to remove the `"${` and the  `}`.

The expected output is: `var.some_text.anothertext.test`, `var.some_text3` and/or `var.some_text2.anothertext`.

How can I achieve that using Regex?

Comment: It seems like regex is not what you're after, but rather a way to extract the variables from the strings. What language are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    "\$\{(.*?)\}"
Replace: "$1"
```

### Demo